# Django ORM join subtable in query

Tags: python, django, django-orm

I want use `Django ORM`. I build SQL query:

```
select itinerary.id, count(users.home_location_id) from itinerary_itinerary as itinerary left join (select to_applicationuser_id as id, users.home_location_id from custom_auth_applicationuser_friends as friends join custom_auth_applicationuser as users on friends.to_applicationuser_id = users.id where from_applicationuser_id = 28)
    as users on itinerary.location_id = users.home_location_id 
    WHERE user_id = 28 
    GROUP BY itinerary.id, users.home_location_id
```

Could anybody tell me how make left join with table from subquery?
28 is current user_id.
I use something like:

```
Itinerary.object.filter(user_id=28).extra(
            tables=['(select to_applicationuser_id as id, users.home_location_id from custom_auth_applicationuser_friends as friends join custom_auth_applicationuser as users on friends.to_applicationuser_id = users.id where from_applicationuser_id = 28) as users'],
            where=['itinerary.location_id = users.home_location_id']
        )
```

But I got error

> ProgrammingError relation "(select to_applicationuser_id as id,
>   users.home_location_id fro" does not exist

**UPD**

Models (it is just simple scheme):

```
class ApplicationUser(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    home_location = models.ForeignKey(Location)
    friends = models.ManyToManyFieled('self')

class Location(models.Model):
    loc_name = models.CharFiled(max_length=255)

class Itinerary(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(ApplicationUser)
    location = models.ForeignKey(Location)
```

Comment: Please post your models (at least the relevant fields).

Answer (score 1):

When you add tables with extra, they get added to the from list, which does not accept an sql statement.
I don't think you need to use extra at all here, you can get a similar query with the ORM without the need to join on a select statement. The following code, using filtering and annotations, will give the same results as much as I was able to understand your query:

```
ApplicationUser.objects.filter(
    Q(itinerary__location_id = F('friends__home_location_id')) |
    Q(friends__home_location__isnull=True),
    id=28,                                                    
    ).values_list(
        'itinerary__id', 'friends__home_location_id'
    ).annotate(location_count = Count('friends__home_location_id')
    ).values_list('itinerary__id', 'location_count')
```

Comment: I want get table which contains `itinerary_id, count friends.homelocation_id` and for itinerary which does not have friend.home_location_id I want get 0. Your's first case, return right answer but without itineraries with 0 home_location_id. Second case is wrong.

Comment: I revised the query, take a look.

Comment: It's work, but still doesn't return rows where location_count  is 0.